# Center map on window with random number

Tags: google-maps-api-3, centering

I am new to this forum (this is my first post) and a beginner in using google map with javascript. I hope I apologize if the question is silly.

I have an arrangement with several cities and want to focus the map according to the result of a random number. I'm using the attached code, but does not work me. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
<script>
var myrand=0
function initialize() {
var i;
var Locations = [
    {
        lat: 40.7127837,
        lon: -74.00594130000002,
        title: "New york",
        description: "I'm number 1"
    },
    {
        lat: 23.634501,
        lon: -102.55278399999997,
        title: "Mexico",
        description: "I'm number 2"
    },
    {
        lat: 36.778261,
        lon: -119.41793239999998,
        title: "California",
        description: "I'm number 3"
    }
];

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.011902,-98.48424649999998),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

//var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// loop over our array
for (i = 0; i < Locations.length; i++) {
    // create a marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: Locations[i].title,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(Locations[i].lat, Locations[i].lon),
        map: map
    });

    // add an event listener for this marker
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, "<p>" + Locations[i].description +  "</p>");
    //bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, Locations[i].description);
}
}

  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          //alert("seleccionado el "+html);
      });
  } 

  function aleatorio(min,max)
{
    myrand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    alert('salió '+ myrand);
    map.setCenter({lat: Locations[myrand].lat, lng: Locations[myrand].lon}); 
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Where/How are you calling `aleatorio`?  What exactly do you expect to happen when you do?  I get a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Math.myrandom is not a function`

Comment: ¡Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your code:

1. the random number function in javascript is Math.random, not Math.myrandom.
2. the function `aleatorio` depends on the array `Locations` being in scope.  Currently that array is local to the initialize function.  You either need to move `aleatorio` inside the `initialize` function or move the `Locations` array into the global namespace.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLLj7cam/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var myrand = 0

function initialize() {
  var i;
  var Locations = [{
    lat: 40.7127837,
    lon: -74.00594130000002,
    title: "New york",
    description: "I'm number 1"
  }, {
    lat: 23.634501,
    lon: -102.55278399999997,
    title: "Mexico",
    description: "I'm number 2"
  }, {
    lat: 36.778261,
    lon: -119.41793239999998,
    title: "California",
    description: "I'm number 3"
  }];

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.011902, -98.48424649999998),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
  });

  // loop over our array
  for (i = 0; i < Locations.length; i++) {
    // create a marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      title: Locations[i].title,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(Locations[i].lat, Locations[i].lon),
      map: map
    });

    // add an event listener for this marker
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, "<p>" + Locations[i].description + "</p>");
  }
  aleatorio(0, 2);

  function aleatorio(min, max) {
    myrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    map.setCenter({
      lat: Locations[myrand].lat,
      lng: Locations[myrand].lon
    });
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    //alert("seleccionado el "+html);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```